# Pandas Change Default Style of Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formatting, xlsxwriter

I am running `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=NAME, index=False)` to output a dataframe to an Excel spreadsheet.

The [Format Default](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html) for xlsxwriter is Calibri 11 with all other properties turned off. Is there a way to change this?

All solutions I have found involve setting `pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None` but this is just for the header.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell_format.set_font_name()` for example:

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_font_name('Times New Roman')
```

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_font_name

You can also use `.set_font_size()` for example:

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_font_size(30)`
```

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_font_size

Comment: This does not change the default format when I use `df.to_excel()`